# What does ({;}) and ({0;}) in a macro definition signify?

Tags: c, macros, lustre

I was going through the lustre source code and was stuck at the macro definition:

```
#define ldlm_namespace_proc_unregister(ns)      ({;})  
#define ldlm_namespace_proc_register(ns)        ({0;})
```

defined in the file `lustre/ldlm/ldlm_resource.c`.
What does this macro definition signify?

Comment: Macros are a plain text replacement. This macro means that a piece of code `ldlm_namespace_proc_register(x)` will be transformed to `({0;})`. Nothing more and nothing less.

Comment: @M.M You need to make that an answer.

Comment: @CareyGregory OK although I suspect it's an XY problem and OP really wants to know what `({0;})` does

Comment: @M.M Yeah, likely so.

Comment: Seems like complete nonsense code? I can't come up with a case where `({;})` would be valid C code. Maybe it is just a failed attempt of writing `;`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Macros are a plain text replacement. This macro means that a piece of code `ldlm_namespace_proc_register(x)` will be transformed to `({0;})`. Nothing more and nothing less.

If you are also wondering about the meaning of the code `({;})` and `({0;})` then these are [GCC expression statements](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html).

According to that documentation, `({0;})` should be exactly the same as `0`, and `({;})` is an expression of type `void`.

---

Speculation follows: the purpose of these macros might be to support the user of the library writing code like this:

```
int result = ldlm_namespace_proc_register(x);
// ...
ldlm_namespace_proc_unregister(x);
```

but also that depending on compiler switches or other configuration, this code may either actually call a function, or in the case where your lines are enabled, actually do nothing.

Comment: Thanks @M.M, one more question, so does it relate in any way to the return value of the function?

Comment: @bhagyeshdudhediya what function?

Comment: return value of `ldlm_namespace_proc_register();`

Comment: @bhagyeshdudhediya macros don't have return values . When these macros are active there is no function, the code `ldlm_namespace_proc_register(x);` is equivalent to the code `0;`

Comment: In the same file I have function definition for :    
`int ldlm_namespace_proc_register(struct ldlm_namespace *ns)`
and also the macro  
`#define ldlm_namespace_proc_register(ns)        ({0;})`  
and the call to function is  
`rc = ldlm_namespace_proc_register(ns);`  
That's why there is confusion about how would be the flow?

Comment: @bhagyeshdudhediya the macro is a text replacement. You probably do not actually have both of those things activated at once in the same file. There will be `#ifdef` or `#if` lines which select one or the other. You could inspect the result of preprocessing if your compiler supports it (e.g. for gcc use the `gcc -E` switch).

Answer (score 1):

@bhagyesh: whatever M.M said is correct and If you see lustre/ldlm/ldlm_resource.c, In line 74 you have

```
74 #ifdef LPROCFS
   .......
   .......
 385 #undef MAX_STRING_SIZE
 386 #else /* LPROCFS */
 387
 388 #define ldlm_namespace_proc_unregister(ns)      ({;})
 389 #define ldlm_namespace_proc_register(ns)        ({0;})
 390

 391 #endif /* LPROCFS */
```

So here these functions are getting manipulated depending on defination of LPROCFS. I think It is visible now.

And about your question..

> Thanks @M.M, one more question, so does it relate in any way to the return value of the function? –
>
> > Here is small experiment in which it is clear...

```
#include<stdio.h>

#ifdef LPROCFS
int my_register(int x)
{
        int y = x*x;
        printf("In my_register val=%d\n", x);
        return y;
}

void my_unregister(int x)
{
        printf("In my_unregister val=%d\n", x);
}

#else

#define my_register(x) ({0;})
#define my_unregister(x) ({;})

#endif

int main ()
{
        printf("In main\n");
        int rc = my_register(2);
        my_unregister(3);
        printf("after returning rc=%d\n", rc);
        return 0;
}
```

When LPROCFS not defined..

```
[root@ashish-203 lustre-wc-rel]# ./test_directives
In main
after returning rc=0
```

When LPROCFS is defined...

```
[root@ashish-203 lustre-wc-rel]# ./test_directives
In main
In my_register val=2
In my_unregister val=3
after returning rc=4
[root@ashish-203 lustre-wc-rel]#
```

Comment: Thats really a great example..
Thanks @Ashish Maurya